# Slide toggling a div in a dynamically created div's which have the same class names

Tags: jquery, html

```
my html is as follows 
<div class="t">
     <div class="t_sliding"></div>
     <div class="t_inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="t">
     <div class="t_sliding"></div>
     <div class="t_inner"></div>
</div>
```

my jquery code is as follows

```
 $(".t_inner").click(function(e) {
        $(".t_sliding").slideToggle(1000);
    });
```

right now , when i click on "t_inner" ,only the first div's "t_sliding" div gets slidetoggled,how can i fix it ?``

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".t_sliding").each(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with clicks on dynamically created elements, you need to look at event delegation:

```
$("body").on("click", ".t_inner",  function(e) {
     $(".t_sliding").slideToggle(1000);
});
```

So all future elements added will have the same event bound to them.